# How to add two different elements from the same array which changes dynamically?

Tags: python

I want to find the difference between the last element and the second last element of the array where the array changes dynamically.

Please go through the code.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import datetime, threading
LTP_arr=[]
url = 'https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO .jsp?underlying=RELIANCE&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=30MAY2019&type=-&strike=-'

def ltw():
    resp = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(resp.content, 'lxml')
    data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#responseDiv').text.strip())
    LTP=data['data'][0]['lastPrice']
    LTP_arr.append(LTP)
    print(LTP_arr)
    threading.Timer(1, tvwap).start()   

ltw()
```

At a particular time if the  array is LTP_arr=['34','65','66','32','81']
Output should be given as 49.
Then on next time frame if the LTP_arr=['34','65','66','32','81','100']
output sholuld be shown as 19

Comment: What is `ltw()`? Your code is very poorly formatted. However, use `int(LTP_arr[-1])-int(LTP_arr[-2])`. Surround the expression with `abs()` if you want the absolute value.

Comment: Indenting is important in python. Please reformat your code. I don't know when you function ends.

Comment: Thank you. Will take care of the format henceforth

Answer (score 2):

You can access last element with `[-1]`
`LTP_arr[-1]` give you '81', which is a `string`. Cast with `int()`
You can do the same thing with [-2]

```
int(LTP_arr[-1]) - int(LTP_arr[-2])
```

You can add a try / except if your value can be cast by `int()`

```
try:
    int(LTP_arr[-1]) - int(LTP_arr[-2])
except IndexError:
    # do what you want to handle this error
```

Comment: You will want a `try/except` for `IndexError` as well.

Comment: I edit my post :) But sometimes you are sure about the data type. So try/except can be avoid if you know the data source